# checkbox value from webstorage performing function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, web-storage

I have multiple checkboxes which when clicked, add an eventSource to my jquery fullcalendar. When I refresh the page, I can retrieve the checkbox values from storage but the event sources are not added. I have to uncheck and then recheck the checkbox.

Here is the function clicking on an indivual checkbox performs.

```
$("#checkbox1").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'EventListRed.php');
    } else {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', 'EventListRed.php');
    }
});
```

and here is how I using web storage to keep the checkbox values

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        var box = boxes[i];
        if (box.hasAttribute("store")) {
            setupBox(box);
        }
    }

    function setupBox(box) {
        var storageId = box.getAttribute("store");
        var oldVal = localStorage.getItem(storageId);
        box.checked = oldVal === "true" ? true : false;
        box.addEventListener("change", function() {
            localStorage.setItem(storageId, this.checked);
        });
    }
});
```

EDIT:

I have added [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5wMUx/116/) as requested.
As you can see the checkbox value is saved, but my events aren't loaded from EventsListRed.php.

Please Note, I am unsure how to link the .php file in the jsfiddle.

I think my issue is I marking the checkbox as checked but its not triggering the change function.

Comment: can you please provide a [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: JSFiddle added. Please see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call .fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' ) before you check that box is checked.

Please see official docs for [refetchEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_data/refetchEvents/)

```
  function setupBox(box) {
    var storageId = box.getAttribute("store");
    var oldVal = localStorage.getItem(storageId);
    $(box).on("change", function() {
      localStorage.setItem(storageId, this.checked);
    });
    box.checked = oldVal === "true" ? true : false;
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' ); 
    if (box.checked) {   
      $(box).trigger('change');

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get what you wanted to achieve but it's seems like a hack.
See [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1qhkjhut/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbRed" store="checkbox3" class="chk" />
<label for="cbRed">Red</label>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#calendar {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },


  });

  //Checkbox removing/adding red events
  $("#cbRed").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'EventListRed.php');
    } else {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', 'EventListRed.php');
    }

  });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");

  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    var box = boxes[i];
    if (box.hasAttribute("store")) {
      setupBox(box);
    }
  }

  function setupBox(box) {
    var storageId = box.getAttribute("store");
    var oldVal = localStorage.getItem(storageId);
    $(box).on("change", function() {
      localStorage.setItem(storageId, this.checked);
    });
    box.checked = oldVal === "true" ? true : false;
    if (box.checked) {
      $(box).trigger('change');
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: You can see in the console that the php call is triggered. There's no way to load server side language code into JsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Weirdly it's still not showing the events for me on refresh, but when I move to previous or next day they load. it's like I need to refresh the calendar when the page is revisted. I have tried adding .fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' ) and also .fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' ) after triggering the change but still not visible instantly after page refresh.